# currency convertion with two currencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I'm currently playing around with a currency converter and I need help on how to enable users to choose whatever currencyTo they want, just as the currencyFrom.

Currently, the conversion is only from USD (which is set to 1) and then converted into a chosen currency. How can I allow users to choose another currency than USD and it still calculates the correct rate?

```js
/* Connecting HTML currency form with the functionality from JavaScript 
We create a function to convert currencies using API and the value entered by the user.

*/
var calculate = function calculate() {
  
    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value); // Sets the varaible amount to be connected with whatever value the user types in the amount field in HTML
    var select1 = document.getElementById("currencyTo"); // Sets the variable select1 to be connected with currencyTo in HTML 
    var result = document.getElementById("result"); // Sets the variable result to be connected with result in HTML 

/* The calculation for the selected rates
The calculation times the amount the user types with the currency and rate related to the currency
And defines this number equals result
*/
    var number = amount * select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].dataset.rate; 
     result.value = number;
}
  
// The calculate function is initiated as soon as the user types a number in the amount field or change the currency, and displays the result immediately in the result field
// This element allows the user to see the immediate result without pressing a calculate button

  document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("keyup", calculate);
  document.getElementById("currencyTo").addEventListener("change", calculate);

 /* This defines currencies and rates connected witht the specific currency 
The key is the abbreviation of the currency name and the value is the rate connected to each currency*/

function callbackFunc(response){ 
    var currencies = response; 
    var currencies_keys = Object.keys(currencies.quotes); 
    var currencies_values = Object.values(currencies.quotes);

//This ensures that the user can not change the default currency in the currencyFrom field 
    var currencyFrom = document.getElementById("currencyFrom");
    currencyFrom.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); 

// When define that the currencies and its values shoud go to the currencyTo field 
    var currencyTo = document.getElementById("currencyTo");
    var currencySelection = "";

// Here we use a universal function to retrieve the activeUser key from LocalStorage as a string and transforms the values into JavaScript objects using JSON.parse
    var activeUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activeUser'))
   
// This creates a list of all the currencies 
    var currenciesList = [];

    for(i=0; i < currencies_keys.length; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            var currency = currencies_keys[i].substring(0,3); // With this substring we split the currencyFrom and currencyTo into their own strings
        
        }

// With this substring we split the currencyFrom and currencyTo into their own strings and define variables
// And defines that the varibale rate should inherit the values of the currenices_values, which is currencies and quotes  
        var currency = currencies_keys[i].substring(3,6);
        var rate = currencies_values[i];

// Create a variable called currency object that consists of the variables currency and rate 
// Push the object into the currency list 
// We tell our currency converter that whatever the currency the user picks it should inherit the values of the variable currency and rate
        var currencyObject = new Currency(currency, rate);
        currenciesList.push(currencyObject);

        currencySelection += "<option value='" + currency + "' data-rate='" + rate + "'>" + currency + "</option>";
    }
//  Adding the list of currency objects to local storage and transforming the list to a string and displaying predefined currency from activeUser in currencyTo in HTML 
    localStorage.setItem("currencies", JSON.stringify(currenciesList));

    currencyTo.innerHTML = currencySelection;

    currencyTo.value = activeUser.currency.name; 
 }

// set endpoint and your access key
endpoint = 'live'
access_key = '7ff7413fd18c1b9652f371629bd4bb4f';

// Here we get the most recent exchange rates via the "live" endpoint:
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://apilayer.net/api/' + endpoint + '?access_key=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        callbackFunc(json);  
    }
});

//Logout function - redirects to LogIn html when button is clicked
var logout = document.getElementById('logout');
logout.onclick = function() {
    document.location.href = 'login1.html'; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Main page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainpage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="commentbox.css">
    <!--Link to external font from google-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">

    <!--In order for our program to collect rates using API we need to fetch a third party script that are created with ajax and JQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="background" style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524821695732-717b25a38974?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=08f92fcbaca12ac3d128dbc91f447164&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1200&q=80)">
            <h3 class="headline">Currency Converter</h3>
            </div>
  

<!-- Left side Currency converter-->
<div class="float-left" style="width:49%; float: left;">
    <div style="text-align:center">

<!--Currency converter-->
<h5>Currency converter</h5>

<!-- We created a form for the currency conversion-->

<form>
<p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert numbers" id="amount" value=""  style="height:40px;font-size:12pt;width:350px;">
<br>
<br>
<!--This field is set to USD as default which is CurrencyFrom-->
<select id="currencyFrom"style="height:50px;font-size:14pt;width:150px">
    <option value='AED' title='United Arab Emirates Dirham'>AED</option>
   <option value='AFN' title='Afghan Afghani'>AFN</option>
   <option value='ALL' title='Albanian Lek'>ALL</option>
   <option value='AMD' title='Armenian Dram'>AMD</option>
   <option value='ANG' title='Netherlands Antillean Guilder'>ANG</option>
   <option value='AOA' title='Angolan Kwanza'>AOA</option>
   <option value='ARS' title='Argentine Peso'>ARS</option>
   <option value='AUD' title='Australian Dollar'>AUD</option>
   <option value='AWG' title='Aruban Florin'>AWG</option>
   <option value='AZN' title='Azerbaijani Manat'>AZN</option>
   <option value='BAM' title='Bosnia-Herzegovina Convertible Mark'>BAM</option>
   <option value='BBD' title='Barbadian Dollar'>BBD</option>
   <option value='BDT' title='Bangladeshi Taka'>BDT</option>
   <option value='BGN' title='Bulgarian Lev'>BGN</option>
   <option value='BHD' title='Bahraini Dinar'>BHD</option>
   <option value='BIF' title='Burundian Franc'>BIF</option>
   <option value='BMD' title='Bermudan Dollar'>BMD</option>
   <option value='BND' title='Brunei Dollar'>BND</option>
   <option value='BOB' title='Bolivian Boliviano'>BOB</option>
   <option value='BRL' title='Brazilian Real'>BRL</option>
   <option value='BSD' title='Bahamian Dollar'>BSD</option>
   <option value='BTC' title='Bitcoin'>BTC</option>
   <option value='BTN' title='Bhutanese Ngultrum'>BTN</option>
   <option value='BWP' title='Botswanan Pula'>BWP</option>
   <option value='BYN' title='Belarusian Ruble'>BYN</option>
   <option value='BYR' title='Belarusian Ruble'>BYR</option>
   <option value='BZD' title='Belize Dollar'>BZD</option>
   <option value='CAD' title='Canadian Dollar'>CAD</option>
   <option value='CDF' title='Congolese Franc'>CDF</option>
   <option value='CHF' title='Swiss Franc'>CHF</option>
   <option value='CLF' title='Chilean Unit of Account (UF)'>CLF</option>
   <option value='CLP' title='Chilean Peso'>CLP</option>
   <option value='CNY' title='Chinese Yuan'>CNY</option>
   <option value='COP' title='Colombian Peso'>COP</option>
   <option value='CRC' title='Costa Rican Colón'>CRC</option>
   <option value='CUC' title='Cuba Convertible Peso'>CRC</option>
   <option value='CUP' title='Cuban Peso'>CUP</option>
   <option value='CVE' title='Cape Verdean Escudo'>CVE</option>
   <option value='CZK' title='Czech Republic Koruna'>CZK</option>
   <option value='DJF' title='Djiboutian Franc'>DJF</option>
   <option value='DKK' title='Danish Krone'>DKK</option>
   <option value='DOP' title='Dominican Peso'>DOP</option>
   <option value='DZD' title='Algerian Dinar'>DZD</option>
   <option value='EEK' title='Estonian Kroon'>EEK</option>
   <option value='EGP' title='Egyptian Pound'>EGP</option>
   <option value='ERN' title='Eritrean Nakfa'>ERN</option>
   <option value='ETB' title='Ethiopian Birr'>ETB</option>
   <option value='EUR' title='Euro'>EUR</option>
   <option value='FJD' title='Fijian Dollar'>FJD</option>
   <option value='FKP' title='Falkland Islands Pound'>FKP</option>
   <option value='GBP' title='British Pound Sterling'>GBP</option>
   <option value='GEL' title='Georgian Lari'>GEL</option>
   <option value='GGP' title='Guernsey Pound'>GGP</option>
   <option value='GHS' title='Ghanaian Cedi'>GHS</option>
   <option value='GIP' title='Gibraltar Pound'>GIP</option>
   <option value='GMD' title='Gambian Dalasi'>GMD</option>
   <option value='GNF' title='Guinean Franc'>GNF</option>
   <option value='GTQ' title='Guatemalan Quetzal'>GTQ</option>
   <option value='GYD' title='Guyanaese Dollar'>GYD</option>
   <option value='HKD' title='Hong Kong Dollar'>HKD</option>
   <option value='HNL' title='Honduran Lempira'>HNL</option>
   <option value='HRK' title='Croatian Kuna'>HRK</option>
   <option value='HTG' title='Haitian Gourde'>HTG</option>
   <option value='HUF' title='Hungarian Forint'>HUF</option>
   <option value='IDR' title='Indonesian Rupiah'>IDR</option>
   <option value='ILS' title='Israeli New Sheqel'>ILS</option>
   <option value='IMP' title='Manx pound'>IMP</option>
   <option value='INR' title='Indian Rupee'>INR</option>
   <option value='IQD' title='Iraqi Dinar'>IQD</option>
   <option value='IRR' title='Iranian Rial'>IRR</option>
   <option value='ISK' title='Icelandic Króna'>ISK</option>
   <option value='JEP' title='Jersey Pound'>JEP</option>
   <option value='JMD' title='Jamaican Dollar'>JMD</option>
   <option value='JOD' title='Jordanian Dinar'>JOD</option>
   <option value='JPY' title='Japanese Yen'>JPY</option>
   <option value='KES' title='Kenyan Shilling'>KES</option>
   <option value='KGS' title='Kyrgystani Som'>KGS</option>
   <option value='KHR' title='Cambodian Riel'>KHR</option>
   <option value='KMF' title='Comorian Franc'>KMF</option>
   <option value='KPW' title='North Korean Won'>KPW</option>
   <option value='KRW' title='South Korean Won'>KRW</option>
   <option value='KWD' title='Kuwaiti Dinar'>KWD</option>
   <option value='KYD' title='Cayman Islands Dollar'>KYD</option>
   <option value='KZT' title='Kazakhstani Tenge'>KZT</option>
   <option value='LAK' title='Laotian Kip'>LAK</option>
   <option value='LBP' title='Lebanese Pound'>LBP</option>
   <option value='LKR' title='Sri Lankan Rupee'>LKR</option>
   <option value='LRD' title='Liberian Dollar'>LRD</option>
   <option value='LSL' title='Lesotho Loti'>LSL</option>
   <option value='LTL' title='Lithuanian Litas'>LTL</option>
   <option value='LVL' title='Latvian Lats'>LVL</option>
   <option value='LYD' title='Libyan Dinar'>LYD</option>
   <option value='MAD' title='Moroccan Dirham'>MAD</option>
   <option value='MDL' title='Moldovan Leu'>MDL</option>
   <option value='MGA' title='Malagasy Ariary'>MGA</option>
   <option value='MKD' title='Macedonian Denar'>MKD</option>
   <option value='MMK' title='Myanma Kyat'>MMK</option>
   <option value='MNT' title='Mongolian Tugrik'>MNT</option>
   <option value='MOP' title='Macanese Pataca'>MOP</option>
   <option value='MRO' title='Mauritanian Ouguiya'>MRO</option>
   <option value='MUR' title='Mauritian Rupee'>MUR</option>
   <option value='MVR' title='Maldivian Rufiyaa'>MVR</option>
   <option value='MWK' title='Malawian Kwacha'>MWK</option>
   <option value='MXN' title='Mexican Peso'>MXN</option>
   <option value='MYR' title='Malaysian Ringgit'>MYR</option>
   <option value='MZN' title='Mozambican Metical'>MZN</option>
   <option value='NAD' title='Namibian Dollar'>NAD</option>
   <option value='NGN' title='Nigerian Naira'>NGN</option>
   <option value='NIO' title='Nicaraguan Córdoba'>NIO</option>
   <option value='NOK' title='Norwegian Krone'>NOK</option>
   <option value='NPR' title='Nepalese Rupee'>NPR</option>
   <option value='NZD' title='New Zealand Dollar'>NZD</option>
   <option value='OMR' title='Omani Rial'>OMR</option>
   <option value='PAB' title='Panamanian Balboa'>PAB</option>
   <option value='PEN' title='Peruvian Nuevo Sol'>PEN</option>
   <option value='PGK' title='Papua New Guinean Kina'>PGK</option>
   <option value='PHP' title='Philippine Peso'>PHP</option>
   <option value='PKR' title='Pakistani Rupee'>PKR</option>
   <option value='PLN' title='Polish Zloty'>PLN</option>
   <option value='PYG' title='Paraguayan Guarani'>PYG</option>
   <option value='QAR' title='Qatari Rial'>QAR</option>
   <option value='RON' title='Romanian Leu'>RON</option>
   <option value='RSD' title='Serbian Dinar'>RSD</option>
   <option value='RUB' title='Russian Ruble'>RUB</option>
   <option value='RWF' title='Rwandan Franc'>RWF</option>
   <option value='SAR' title='Saudi Riyal'>SAR</option>
   <option value='SBD' title='Solomon Islands Dollar'>SBD</option>
   <option value='SCR' title='Seychellois Rupee'>SCR</option>
   <option value='SDG' title='Sudanese Pound'>SDG</option>
   <option value='SEK' title='Swedish Krona'>SEK</option>
   <option value='SGD' title='Singapore Dollar'>SGD</option>
   <option value='SHP' title='Saint Helena Pound'>SHP</option>
   <option value='SLL' title='Sierra Leonean Leone'>SLL</option>
   <option value='SOS' title='Somali Shilling'>SOS</option>
   <option value='SRD' title='Surinamese Dollar'>SRD</option>
   <option value='STD' title='São Tomé and Príncipe Dobra'>STD</option>
   <option value='SVC' title='Salvadoran Colón'>SVC</option>
   <option value='SYP' title='Syrian Pound'>SYP</option>
   <option value='SZL' title='Swazi Lilangeni'>SZL</option>
   <option value='THB' title='Thai Baht'>THB</option>
   <option value='TJS' title='Tajikistani Somoni'>TJS</option>
   <option value='TMT' title='Turkmenistani Manat'>TMT</option>
   <option value='TND' title='Tunisian Dinar'>TND</option>
   <option value='TOP' title='Tongan Pa?anga'>TOP</option>
   <option value='TRY' title='Turkish Lira'>TRY</option>
   <option value='TTD' title='Trinidad and Tobago Dollar'>TTD</option>
   <option value='TWD' title='New Taiwan Dollar'>TWD</option>
   <option value='TZS' title='Tanzanian Shilling'>TZS</option>
   <option value='UAH' title='Ukrainian Hryvnia'>UAH</option>
   <option value='UGX' title='Ugandan Shilling'>UGX</option>
   <option value='USD' title='United States Dollar'>USD</option>
   <option value='UYU' title='Uruguayan Peso'>UYU</option>
   <option value='UZS' title='Uzbekistan Som'>UZS</option>
   <option value='VEF' title='Venezuelan Bolívar'>VEF</option>
   <option value='VND' title='Vietnamese Dong'>VND</option>
   <option value='VUV' title='Vanuatu Vatu'>VUV</option>
   <option value='WST' title='Samoan Tala'>WST</option>
   <option value='XAF' title='CFA Franc BEAC'>XAF</option>
   <option value='XAG' title='Silver (troy ounce)'>XAG</option>
   <option value='XAU' title='Gold (troy ounce)'>XAU</option>
   <option value='XCD' title='East Caribbean Dollar'>XCD</option>
   <option value='XDR' title='Special Drawing Rights'>XDR</option>
   <option value='XOF' title='CFA Franc BCEAO'>XOF</option>
   <option value='XPF' title='CFP Franc'>XPF</option>
   <option value='YER' title='Yemeni Rial'>YER</option>
   <option value='ZAR' title='South African Rand'>ZAR</option>
   <option value='ZMK' title='Zambian Kwacha (pre-2013)'>ZMK</option>
   <option value='ZMW' title='Zambian Kwacha'>ZWL</option>
   <option value='ZWL' title='Zimbabwean Dollar'>ZWL</option>
</select> 

<!--This is currencyTo where the user can chose the preferred rate. The default will be the rate selected at registration-->
<select id="currencyTo" style="height:50px;font-size:14pt;width:150px">
</select>

<br>
<br>

<!--Here the user will see the calculated result-->
<input type="text" id="result" value="" style="height:40px;font-size:12pt;width:350px; background-color:lightsteelblue">
</p>
</form> 

<!--This button allows users to log out and return to the login page-->
<div id="Footer">
  <input 
  type="button" 
  value="Logout" 
  name="logout" 
  id="logout" />
  </div>

</div>
</div>


<!-- This is the right part of the page, where the comment box is placed -->
<div class="float-right" style="width:49%; float: right;">
  <div class="content">
  <div class="comments">
  <div class="editor">
  <div class="editor-header">
    <a href='#' data-role='bold'>B</a>
    <a href='#' data-role='italic'>I</a>
    <a href='#' data-role='underline'>U</a>
    <a href='#' data-role='justifyleft'><i class="menu-left"></i></a>
    <a href='#' data-role='justifycenter'><i class="menu-center"></i></a>
    <a href='#' data-role='justifyright'><i class="menu-right"></i></a>
  </div>

  <div id="text" class="editor-content" contenteditable palceholder= "Leave a comment">
  </div>
  </div>
                  
  <div class="insert-text">
    <span class="loading">Loading...</span>
    <!--This span class calculates the total comments-->
    <span class="total-comment"></span>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Comment" />
        </p>
  </div>
    <div class="listComments">
                
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
    



<script src="mainpage.js"></script>
<script src="commentbox.js"></script>
<script src ="userclass.js"></script>
<script src="currencyClass.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy: If you want to calculate the rate for a currency pair (let's say XXX/YYY) but you have only `USD/XXX` and `USD/YYY`, simply invert the first (1/x) to make it `XXX/USD` and then multiply by the second.

For example you want `GBP/EUR`:

- You have `USD/GBP` = 0.771188
- You have `USD/EUR` = 0.848514
- Invert `USD/GBP` = `GBP/USD` = 1/0.771188 = 1.2967
- ➡️ `GBP/EUR` = `GBP/USD` * `USD/EUR` (note: `USD` cancels out) = 1.2967 * 0.848514 = 1.100269

If you want `EUR/GBP`, it's the other way round, invert `USD/EUR` and multiply by `USD/GBP`. Always make sure your "intermediate" rate (`USD` in that case) ends up in the middle, so it is eliminated.

With this simple trick, you can use any currency API like [SWOP foreign exchange rate API](https://swop.cx/) to calculate rates for any base currency even in their free plan.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the programmers of SWOP ;)

A different note: Usually you should avoid including your `access_key` in posts - people could steal it and use up your quota.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you know USD to any currency, you can use that information to convert any currency to any other by converting to and from USD, e.g. € -> $ -> £

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you would do that? I can't get it to work. :)

Comment: It's been a while, but if anyone is interested, check my answer for details how to do it ;) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64212126/7850685